# Is this the right naming convention ?

Tags: java, coding-style, naming-conventions, conventions

Assuming we have a method which calls another.

```
public readXMLFile()  {
    // reading each line and parsing each line to return node.
   Node = parse(line);
}

private parse() {

}
```

Now is it a good practice to use a more comprehensive function name like "readXMLFileAndParse" ?
Pro's: 
It provides a more comprehensive information to caller of what the function is supposed to be doing.
Else client may wonder if it only reads where is the "parse" utility.

In other words I see a clear advantage of a function name to be comprehensive of all the activities nested within it. Is this right thing to do  aka is this considered a good practice ?

Comment: In `Objective C`, method names are obtusely long like your suggested `readXMLFileAndParse`.  I don't think this is really the style in `Java` however.  But in my opinion, it would be better if the outer method's name was focused on the `parse` part, because the end result is a parsed XML file.

Comment: I assume `Node` is some kind of instance variable, in that case it should be in lower/camel case, ie `node = parse(line);` for example.

Comment: Is this a primarily opinion based question with no possibility of a definitive answer? Are you asking whose standard you should follow? I don't know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a guideline that every method can only have one job (single responsibility).
However this will cause problems for the naming where a method will return a result of a combination of sub-methods.

Therefore you should name it to describe its primary function: parsing a file. Reading a file is part of that, but it's not vital to the end-user since it's implicated.

Then again, you have to think of what this exactly entails: nobody just parses a file just to parse it. Do you retrieve data? Do you write data?

You should describe your actions on that file, but not as literally as 'readfile' or 'parsefile'.
`RetrieveCustomers` if you're reading customers would be a lot more descriptive.

```
public List<Customer> RetrieveCustomers() {
 // loop over lines
 // call parser
}

private Customer ParseCustomer() { }
```

If you'd share what exactly it is you're trying to parse, that would help a lot.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/33558/dom-parser-implemented-from-scratch-code-review-request  I am concerned about naming 2 functions, one that I have called `pareXMLDoc` and other one as `readAndParse`. Want some better naming there. Thanks

Comment: Your naming is ambiguous: first you have a method `parseXMLDoc()` which calls `readAndParse()` which calls `parseLine()`. Reading is part of the parsing process. Unless you first read it and store it inside memory, these shouldn't even be set apart. Have a method `ParseXML()` and `ParseLine()` and you're done. You can merge the first two methods together.

Comment: due to recursive nature, the first and second cannot be combined together

Comment: @JavaDeveloper: then call them `ParseXMLTree()`, `ParseDocument` and `ParseLine()`. At this point it's becoming subjective, just do whatever feels good while keeping my post in mind. It should describe what your intention is, not how you're doing it.

Comment: sure I totally understand the gist of your feedback

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on the complexity of your class. Since the method is `private`, no-one, in theory, should care. Named it descriptively enough so you can read your own code 6 months from now, and stop there.

`public` methods, on the other hand, should be well-named and well-documented. Extra descriptiveness there can't hurt.